# Find first value in array with set num difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given a sorted array, I am looking to find the first value in the array where the next value has an increase/difference of >=1000. In the below array, my goal is to return the value 11710, because the next value in array (13271) has a difference of >= 1000.

**Sample Array**

```
const array = [11006, 11256, 11310, 11710, 13271, 327027, 327027]
```

**Current Code** // not returning correct value

```
const found = array.find((element, index) => {
   console.log('element', element),
   console.log('array[index + 1]', array[index + 1])
   return Math.abs(element, array[index + 1]) >= 1000
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the *difference*, so you should use `-`. `Math.abs` does not accept multiple arguments.

```js
const array = [11006, 11256, 11310, 11710, 13271, 327027, 327027]
const found = array.find((element, index) => {
   return Math.abs(element - array[index + 1]) >= 1000
})
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is sorted. So you can be sure that the next element is always greater than the previous one. So you don't need to call the `abs` function at all.

```js
const array = [11006, 11256, 11310, 11710, 13271, 327027, 327027];
const found = array.find((element, index) => { 
  return array[index + 1] - element >= 1000;
});
console.log(found);
```

This should be enough.